# How to scatter dots using time series data(X axis) and ratio(Y axis) using matlab

Tags: matlab, plot, scatter-plot, time-format

I want to scatter dots on the graph with HH:mm:ss on x-axis and percentage on y-axis.
First, I imported data from excel by the menu on Matlab.

I used the below code to transfer to time format(X values, It shows as time format).

```
t =days(VarName6);
t.Format='hh:mm:ss';
```

Then, somehow there appears an error message saying "In order to change from duration to number format choose one of SECONDS, MINUTES, HOURS, DAYS, YEARS".

Anyway 't' is time(HH:MM:SS) format(250 of them) and 'VarName5' is in numbers(0.0471, etc.)(250 of them).
I want to set x axis From 5AM until 1AM. And convert Y axis unit in to ratio(%).
How should I change the code to?

```
hold on;
sz=140;
scatter(t,VarName5,sz,'d');
grid on 
xlabel('time'); 
ylabel('ratio');
title('Samsung Station')
hold off
saveas(1,'figure 1.jpg')
```

I keep getting the below image as graph. But I want to scatter 250 dots on graph.
[image: result I keep getting as data connected graph]

Comment: I am currently using 2015a version

Answer (score 2):

Boom! That was simple

```
figure(1)
hold on;
scatter(datenum(t),VarName5*100,'b');
grid on 
xlabel('time'); 
ylabel('ratio(%)');
%title('Samsung Station')
datetick('x', 'HH:MM:SS', 'keeplimits')
hold off
saveas(1,'figure 1.jpg')
```

[image: result]